# Correct use of Deduct and Deducted

Tags: sentence-construction

Once we **deduct/deducted** it we have to deduct this for next six month.

What should I use in above sentence Deduct or Deducted?

Is it something like

a) If we deduct it once the we will have to deduct this for next six month.

b) If we deducted it once then we would have to deduct this for next six month.

Comment: You need “six month” to be “six months”; remember, it’s plural.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is; a) After a bit of modification: "If we are going to deduct it once, then we will have to deduct it for the next six months".
I think that is the correct answer. Because initially, you are starting the conversation with the present tense, which is "If we are going to deduct something (which focuses on the present event)". The other section is the fact that you are estimating the consequence of your present decision which is going to impact your future (in the future tense); "then we will have to deduct this for the next six months".